# How to fire two alarms at same time in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I'm creating an reminder based application.When user creates reminder at any time it is working fine.But if he created two alarms at the same time(I'm not taking sec into consideration)let's say 9:30 am.Second alarm is firing correctly but first one is coming after one minute i.e 9:31.

This is how I'm creating alarm:`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),60000, contentIntent);`

There I have given repeat time is 60000ms that is why it is coming after 1min.

But I want two alarms to be triggered at the same time.I've tried with remaining 3 methods of "AlarmManager" class but nothing works.Any suggestions to achieve this.

This is my create alarm method:

```
    public void createAlarm(Context context,int id,String title,String date1,String voiceMsgUrl, String description, String owner,String type, String repFrequency)
    {
        eventIntent=new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class);
        eventIntent.putExtra("notifyId", id+"");
        eventIntent.putExtra("title",title);
        eventIntent.putExtra("date", date1);
        eventIntent.putExtra("voiceMsgUrl", voiceMsgUrl);
        eventIntent.putExtra("description", description);
        eventIntent.putExtra("owner", owner);
        eventIntent.putExtra("repFrequency", repFrequency);

        contentIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, eventIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try{

            date=format.parse(date1);
            calendar.setTime(date);

        }catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(calendar.getTimeInMillis()>System.currentTimeMillis()){

            AppzoyDebug.e("creating alarm at time", calendar.getTimeInMillis()+"  lll");
        alarmManager=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


   //alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),3000, contentIntent);


        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), contentIntent);

        }
    }
```

I'm passing values to that method like below

```
alarm.createAlarm(ReminderActivity.this, id, title.getText().toString(), dueDate.getText().toString(), url, description.getText().toString(), ownerNameString, "REM",repFrequency);
```

Comment: Have you tried `setExact()`?

Comment: Yes.I tried that's  not firing the second alarm at all.

Comment: Are you using a different `requestCode` for the two alarms?

Comment: yes i'm using different request codes for both.This is how i'm creating pending intent "contentIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, eventIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);"

Comment: @DanielNugent if the requestCode was the same (and the Intents similar enough), the alarm would only fire once. But it seems that both the alarms are fired, just not at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, since API level 19 pretty much all alarms are inexact.  I would think that using `setExact()` would be your best bet.  Can you post your code that you tried with `setExact()`?

Comment: Also, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24724859/alarmmanager-setexact-with-wakefulbroadcastreceiver-sometimes-not-exact/24776900#24776900

Comment: @DanielNugent this is how i tried with setExact() method. alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), contentIntent);

Comment: Can you edit that into the question, and include both alarms, including the calendar setup and also `PendingIntent` and `Intent` setup?

Comment: Please check i've updated my question

Comment: Use one alarm, and have the receiver immediately fire the other intent.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede i didn't get that, can you please explain once.

Comment: So the user chooses two alarms in the UI of your app with the same time, correct?  Then this function gets called each time the user sets an alarm?

Comment: Yes, when ever user enter the data and clicks "ok" this method will be called

Comment: Have the receiver for your `eventIntent` fire your `contentIntent`, or vice versa.

Comment: yes i have broadcast receiver which will call when ever the alarm fires up.

Comment: So when you used `setExact()` the first alarm fired at exactly the right time, and the second one didn't fire at all?

Comment: No the second one is firing and first one is being ignored means not fired at all.For ex let's say my two alarms are A and B.First i create A and next B.B is getting fired but not A.

Comment: sorry @DanielNugent it's my mistake i'm not handling the second alarm.Kind of idiot i am.

Comment: @venky haha, we all have those moments.  So is it working for you now?

Comment: yes it's working perfect,Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: @venky: Did you get a solution to this .. If so, could you post the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Use 2 different Alarm manager. 1 alarm manager has set 1 alarm at a time. So if you want to set more than 1 alarm at the same time then set different Alarm Manager for each alarm..

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  Can you post code how you think this would work?

Comment: Ya this work properly for each alarm has set different alarm manager. when 2 alarm is set same time.. this case that only option in think.

Answer (score -1):

Use `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` in place of `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`and check it.

Comment: I don't think that would work.  That just makes the alarm timing based on time since the last boot time of the device: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938213/android-alarmmanager-rtc-wakeup-vs-elapsed-realtime-wakeup

Comment: Try with different Intent objects and different Request Code for same Alarm Manager Object